# User without username with allauth, rest_auth and facebook

Tags: django, facebook, rest

I have a setup with django-rest-framework, rest-auth, allauth and facebook Oauth2. My problem here is that when I created an user using the facebook endpoint, the social user was created, the django user was also created but both have no username. Should I configure this somewhere?

Comment: i had a similar problem, is there another user with a duplicate email of the facebook account?

Comment: Nope, just one, mine, as I'm still developing it. I'm really not into looking into the source code. Hope doesn't come to it.

Comment: ok, different issue then. Good luck!

Comment: Did you set ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True? Also check this settings SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP. I believe you'll need to set it false.

Comment: Having exact same problem. Any Solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

The `username` field is no longer present, because it was deprecated with Graph API v2.0 one year ago...

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> `/me/username` is no longer available.

Check if you're using the newest versions of your libraries.

Comment: How could I set a custom username then? An empty username makes it hard to use the admin.

Comment: This is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can set custom username by overriding ***DefaultSocialAccountAdapter***
i just removed @ from **email** and replaced by **_** to generate username

```
#in setting added this

SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'trip2.users.adapter.SocialAdapter'

# and then override the Adapter

class SocialAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):


    def populate_user(self,
                  request,
                  sociallogin,
                  data):
    """
    Hook that can be used to further populate the user instance.

    For convenience, we populate several common fields.

    Note that the user instance being populated represents a
    suggested User instance that represents the social user that is
    in the process of being logged in.

    The User instance need not be completely valid and conflict
    free. For example, verifying whether or not the username
    already exists, is not a responsibility.
    """
    username = data.get('username')
    first_name = data.get('first_name')
    last_name = data.get('last_name')
    email = data.get('email')
    name = data.get('name')
    user = sociallogin.user
    emailtouname = email.split('@')[0] + "_" + email.split('@')[1].split('.')[0]

    user_email(user, valid_email_or_none(email) or '')
    name_parts = (name or '').partition(' ')
    user_field(user, 'first_name', first_name or name_parts[0])
    user_field(user, 'last_name', last_name or name_parts[2])
    user_username(user, username or emailtouname)
    return user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a 'username' key along with other data retrieved via Facebook API. Or you can dig into allauth/socialaccount/adapter.py populate_user() method and customize the 'username' field (I simply make it equal to user email)